# Looping through a string, more than one char gets output

Tags: c++, string

I am using C++ and SDL to make a game for fun.

I show the kill count on the screen by turning it into a surface using TTF_RenderText, which needs a `const char*`. There are gaps in between where I want the individual digits to be shown so I split up the string into individual `char`s.

This is the code I wrote to split up the string and render it on the screen:

```
        SpareStream.str("");
        SpareStream << Kills;
        std::string KillsString = SpareStream.str();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            if(i < KillsString.size()) 
            {
                std::string Cheat = KillsString.substr(i,i+1);
                const char *KillsChar = Cheat.c_str();
                Message = TTF_RenderText_Solid(EightBitLimit,KillsChar,White);
            }
            else Message = TTF_RenderText_Solid(EightBitLimit,"0",White);
            ApplySurface(540 + (45 * i),(500 - HUD->h) + 24,Message,Screen);
        }
```

However, when the kill count exceeds more than 100, this happens:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/XdeCLtc.png]

the tens and ones are shown where only the tens should be.

Why is this happening?

Comment: This sounds like a **bug**. On the face of it, anyway. All I can say is, Merry Christmas! :-)

Comment: I don't know anything about SDL, but the second parameter to `substr` is the length of the substring. I think you'd want it to be `1`, not `i + 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from my reference, std::string::substr is:

```
string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;
```

Thats a start/length pair, not start/end, so you need:

```
 std::string Cheat = KillsString.substr(i,1);
```

btw, while start/length pairs are rarely use for containers in teh standard library, they were so universal for char* management in C that it does frequently turn up in the string classes.

Comment: This worked, thank you. I guess I need to read the documentation more carefully.